# Bare-Metal C: Why are some IDEs startup files doing things crt0.s would take care of anyway?

Tags: c, gcc, startup, crt, bare-metal

I'm writing bare-metal C software for the ARM Cortex-M3 microcontroller STM32F4 using [Em::Blocks IDE](http://www.emblocks.org/).

[Here's the content of the startup_stm32f429x.S file which is included with the IDE.](http://codetidy.com/6001/)

- At line 169 to 192 you see that the `.data` section is filled with the initial values.
- At line 199 it is branching to the `_start` symbol, which is defined in crt0.s file of my [GCC toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)
- At line 211 to 223 is providing it's own code for clearing the `.bss` section. (Here, `_start` is defined again, but weak. Hence this code is only active in case the `_start` symbol wasn't defined anywhere else.)

My questions are:

- Why is the startup file providing code for initializing `.data` and clearing `.bss`? I thought that's the job of crt0.s?!
- As I mentioned, the code for clearing `.bss` seems only to be active in case crt0.s is missing.

  - This sounds like crt0.s could be missing sometimes. Why would crt0.s be missing? Why can't you rely on it being available? Under which circumstances would it be missing?
  - Why is, in contrast to that, the initialization of the `.data` section *always* active, independently of crt0.s being available or not?

---

### Update

I've just read, that setting up the exception vectors [is another thing crt0.s is responsible for](http://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean9/html/ch05s02.html). So again: Why is this in my [startup file](http://codetidy.com/6001/) done at line 41 to 151?

Answer (score 0):

exactly because you don't want to use gcc's crt0 on a bare-metal microcontroller, if you don't need its functionality. If you don't use crt0, then you'll have to do it yourself.